# empty($_POST) === FALSE VS !empty($_POST)

Tags: php

I'm doing a tutorial, and whoever wrote it keeps using code like

```
if (empty($_POST) === false)
```

Why would you not just use

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

Is there a reason for this that I'm missing?  It seems unnecessarily confusing to use the first method rather than the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=== enforces type checking.

For example

```
if(false == 0)//evaluates to true

if(false === 0)//evaluates to false
```

In your example above, just doing !empty() is the same as doing == (well, technically !=)

So how do we explain this? 0 can either represent the value 0, or false, since traditionally a 0 bit means false (1 means true, although now anything non 0 is considered true). The problem you run into with a dynamically typed language like PHP is that there is no implicit type checking done on two arguments, so you can compare a boolean with a number and get a true result in situations where it should be false.

The [strpos()](https://www.php.net/strpos) function in PHP is an EXCELLENT example of where this is important

Comment: SO am I correct in thinking that I should be using === wherever possible?  Because this is a more strict check?

Comment: That's up to you. It adds overhead, but if it's used correctly it's not really a big deal.

Comment: @hyphen: In php if you use `===` it will make a further reader to spend another time thinking **why** it's been used in this particular place. So don't use `===` unless it's the thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns a `boolean`, it makes, literally, no difference at all. Sounds like someone is just being overly complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
if ($_POST) { ...
```

But it makes not much sense.

If you want to extract something from `_POST` - check if a particular key exists. Just knowing that `post is not empty` is not helpful at all.

Comment: I think it's because your explanation is valid, but doesn't really answer the question as to why the tutorial is doing that. I wouldn't downvote that though

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: I explained that it makes no sense. So regardless of why the tutorial author did that - it makes no sense in a real life. So probably the real answer would be: "the author didn't understand completely what they are doing" but the community won't accept it.

Comment: @zerkms I'm agreeing with you bro.